# what is the TAG_NAME when verify git tags for android-2.3.1_r1?

Tags: android, git

I am a newbie for android. I have just finished downloading source code of android-2.3.1_r1 according to android official guide
(http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html).
after “repo sync”finished comes the “verifying git tags” 
The guide says 'you can verify any tag with
“git tag -v TAG_NAME”',  what shall I use for 'TAG_NAME' when I actually carry out the command.
I tried 'git tag -l' in my android root directory which came out: 
'fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
'
then I tried it in 
android_root_directory/.repo/repo/ which came out: 
'v1.0
v1.0.1
v1.0.2
v1.0.3
v1.0.4
v1.0.5
v1.0.6
v1.0.7
v1.0.8
v1.0.9
v1.1
v1.10.0
v1.10.1
v1.10.2
v1.10.3
v1.10.4
v1.11.0
v1.11.1
v1.12.0
v1.12.1
v1.12.2
v1.2
v1.3
v1.3.1
v1.3.2
v1.4
v1.4.1
v1.4.2
v1.4.3
v1.4.4
v1.5
v1.5.1
v1.6
v1.6.1
v1.6.10
v1.6.10.1
v1.6.10.2
v1.6.2
v1.6.3
v1.6.4
v1.6.5
v1.6.6
v1.6.7
v1.6.7.1
v1.6.7.2
v1.6.7.3
v1.6.7.4
v1.6.7.5
v1.6.8
v1.6.8.1
v1.6.8.10
v1.6.8.11
v1.6.8.2
v1.6.8.3
v1.6.8.4
v1.6.8.5
v1.6.8.6
v1.6.8.7
v1.6.8.8
v1.6.8.9
v1.6.9
v1.6.9.1
v1.6.9.2
v1.6.9.3
v1.6.9.4
v1.6.9.5
v1.6.9.6
v1.6.9.7
v1.6.9.8
v1.7
v1.7.1
v1.7.2
v1.7.3
v1.7.3.1
v1.7.4
v1.7.4.1
v1.7.4.2
v1.7.4.3
v1.7.5
v1.7.6
v1.7.6.1
v1.7.7
v1.7.7.1
v1.7.7.2
v1.7.7.3
v1.7.7.4
v1.7.7.5
v1.7.7.6
v1.7.8
v1.7.8.1
v1.7.8.2
v1.8.0
v1.8.1
v1.8.2
v1.9.0
v1.9.1
v1.9.2
v1.9.3
v1.9.4
v1.9.5
v1.9.6'
 Is one of them I shall use for TAG_NAME? If so, which one? Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0):

In git tags can be signed.

To verify tag you need to have public key with you.

git tag -v TAG_NAME will tell if tag can be verified or not.

As far repo tool concerned repo save public keys in folder ~/.repoconfig/gnupg; so you want set an environment variable GNUPGHOME=~/.repoconfig/gnupg

All said and done verify tag is generally not necessary.

Comment: ”All said and done verify tag is generally not necessary“， so i can just ignore the 'git tag -v TAG_NAME' operation and continue, there won't be any problem?

Comment: I guess so. if you are not sure about data integrity then only verify is needed.